# click on image to add or remove class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of images and I want to add / remove a border and a box shadow on click.
I thought it would be very simple, but it seems i am overlooking something here.

html:

```
<img class='unselected' src='/images/dot.en.hc.png' alt='dot' title='dot' />
```

jquery:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

css:

```
.selected {
    border: 2px solid #0F0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px #0F0;
    transition: border 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s;
}
.unselected {
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #0F0;
    transition: border 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s;
}
```

EDIT: as the code above seems to be fine, I am printing here the full code that I have on the website (I just started this little site now to test few things, so it is quite empty):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('img').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
    }
});
</script>
<style>
img {
    max-width: 50px;
}
.selected {
    border: 2px solid #0F0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px #0F0;
    transition: border 0.2s, opacity 0.2s, filter 0.2s;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
}
.unselected {
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #0F0;
    transition: border 0.2s, opacity 0.2s, filter 0.2s;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="link.php">
<input type="hidden" name="log" value="1"/>
<img class='unselected' src='/images/dot.en.hc.png' id='dot.en.hc' alt='dot.en.hc' title='dot.en.hc' />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for me.  What problem are you having?

Comment: here is your code in a jsfiddle.. **http://jsfiddle.net/u4C64/1/** - it works.. what is the issue? do you have this code in a document ready() method or window.load event to make sure the code runs when all images have loaded?

Comment: Wow, you're right, in the JSfiddle it works perfectly. Weird. On my page it just does not do anything. I check the element and the class does not change. like the jquery does not run or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about checking if the **DOM** is ready and or that the **images have loaded**

http://jsfiddle.net/u4C64/1/

also with code below:

**ready()**:
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
// wait until DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function(){

    // wait until all images are loaded
    $(window).on("load", function(){

         $('img').click(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                 $(this).removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
            } else {
                 $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
            }    
        });

    }); 

});
```

Comment: This actually solved the problem!! Thanks. But one question remains: why does this make the difference? I did wait until the site was fully loaded, etc. before I attempted to click. Explanation?

Comment: @koljanep the ready() function waits until the DOM (all html markup) has loaded.. the window load event waits until all images, links, assets are fully loaded.. Thats why i put the window load event inside the ready() method to make sure the DOM is ready before running the load event, because sometimes the DOM might be ready before the images are loaded due to browser inconsistencies, network, and image size.. .. Its always best to wait until all images have been loaded before trying to do anything with them :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead of adding and removing the class.

Also, wrap it with `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected unselected');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a little cleaner than the OP's code, but functionally it is no different so it wouldn't solve any problem that OP is having.

Comment: @andi OP doesn't has any problem with his code. He just needs a better one.

Comment: I got the impression, based on his question, that it wasn't working for him.  But I am not 100% sure what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').click(function() {
   if( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).toggleClass(' unselected selected');
    }
    else{
         $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Check the working & updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4C64/2/)